Unable to get data from sharePoint with msal browser using react
Description
I need to get data from the SharePoint list with simple react application.
I am unable to get data from SharePoint with msal browser.
Error Message
I face below error

MSAL Configuration
    const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "<client-id>",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token",
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/",
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage", // Configure as per your requirement
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
    },
};

Relevant Code Snippets


const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const initializeMsal = async () => {
    if (!msalInstance.getAllAccounts().length) {
        await msalInstance.initialize();  // Make sure to initialize the instance
    }
};

const getAccessToken = async () => {
    await initializeMsal(); // Ensure MSAL is initialized
    const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
    if (accounts.length > 0) {
        const request = {
            scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/"],
            account: accounts[0],
        };

        try {
            const response = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request);
            return response.accessToken;
        } catch (error) {
            if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
                return msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup(request).then((response) => {
                    return response.accessToken;
                });
            } else {
                console.error("Error acquiring token silently:", error);
            }
        }
    } else {
        const loginRequest = {
            scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/"],
        };
        const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest);
        return loginResponse.accessToken;
    }
};




Wild guess here but: The authority URL in your msalConfig might be incorrect. Typically, the authority URL should look like this:
authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
Your current authority URL is pointing to https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token, which is incorrect. The /oauth2/token endpoint is used for acquiring tokens directly and isn't typically part of the authority in MSAL configuration.
